# Alexa Rank: No Data

Tags: seo, alexa-internet

I own a domain and host for more than **2 years**. I get **No Data** in **alexa** rank.
I **claimed** my website in alexa for more than a month. But I still get No Data.
Should I use a special technique to have my website indexed in alexa?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about SEO and Alexa rankings, and not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No data by Alexa usually means they have not recorded (or estimated) little or no traffic or visits for the last 3 months. This is what Alexa says about the same -

> Alexa’s traffic rankings are based on the past three months of global
>   traffic measured from our global traffic panel and are updated daily.
>   An overall traffic ranking of “No data”, or “No rank” in the Toolbar,
>   indicates that none of our sources show visits to the site in question
>   during the past three months (as of our last update).

Do you have any analytics deployed? If yes, do you record any traffic (excluding your own)?

Comment: I recorded sime traffic in Google analytics.

Comment: Usually Alexa does not rank websites with little or no traffic to avoid overloading their servers/bandwidth. Its a major grey area  when it comes to their internal ranking requirements. Try building some traffic and re-check. Don't worry, it's got nothing to do with your website as a design or coding. If its indexed by Google, Alexa will do so for sure.

Comment: My site listed after 2 month, then ranking change everyday. In GA counted 2k visitor, ranking 4m & 500k in US, that weird

Answer (score 0):

Running Google Analytics on your site shouldn't have any impact on whether you're listed on Alexa or not. Listing on Alexa is entirely a measure of traffic quantity over a 90-day period. If your website doesn't generate significant traffic, it will not be listed.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought to share an answer that I was able to discover to start ranking in
Alexa's radius. Some of the blogging wizards say that follow three steps to get
your site/blog recognized by Alexa-

> A) Install Alexa toolbar into your Firefox and Chrome browsers.
>
> B) Install a Alexa Rank Plugin or Add Alexa Ranking code into your
> Blog or site.
>
> C) Do something to drive traffic to your website or blog.

If someone finds a better idea, kindly do share it. I just followed the above
three, and waiting for Alexa to rank my blog. I did add a Text Widget to my blog
and embed the Alexa Rank HTML code. If you like, can check it from
[TechBeamers.com](http://www.TechBeamers.com).